# onConfigurationChanged stuck in infinite loop, App crashes on orientation change

Tags: android, androidx

I'll start off by saying that I have isolated this to a change in Android 13 Tiramisu. When my app is compiled targeting API 32 or lower there are no issues and the app handles orientation changes without issue, but when I change the target API to 33 (or even 34) the following issue happens:

When I rotate the device triggering onConfigurationChanged to be called in my Activity, it results in an infinite loop causing the app to crash with a StackOverFlowError, here is the stacktrace:

```
at com.myapp.MainActivity.onConfigurationChanged(MainActivity.java:1052)
at android.content.ComponentCallbacksController.lambda$dispatchConfigurationChanged$0(ComponentCallbacksController.java:91)
at android.content.ComponentCallbacksController$$ExternalSyntheticLambda2.accept(Unknown Source:4)
at android.content.ComponentCallbacksController.forAllComponentCallbacks(ComponentCallbacksController.java:124)
at android.content.ComponentCallbacksController.dispatchConfigurationChanged(ComponentCallbacksController.java:91)
at android.app.Activity.onConfigurationChanged(Activity.java:3066)
at androidx.activity.ComponentActivity.onConfigurationChanged(ComponentActivity.java:865)
at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onConfigurationChanged(FragmentActivity.java:262)
at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.onConfigurationChanged(AppCompatActivity.java:229)
at com.myapp.MainActivity.onConfigurationChanged(MainActivity.java:1052)
at android.content.ComponentCallbacksController.lambda$dispatchConfigurationChanged$0(ComponentCallbacksController.java:91)
at android.content.ComponentCallbacksController$$ExternalSyntheticLambda2.accept(Unknown Source:4)
at android.content.ComponentCallbacksController.forAllComponentCallbacks(ComponentCallbacksController.java:124)
at android.content.ComponentCallbacksController.dispatchConfigurationChanged(ComponentCallbacksController.java:91)
at android.app.Activity.onConfigurationChanged(Activity.java:3066)
at androidx.activity.ComponentActivity.onConfigurationChanged(ComponentActivity.java:865)
at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onConfigurationChanged(FragmentActivity.java:262)
at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.onConfigurationChanged(AppCompatActivity.java:229)
... (it repeats like this until it causes a stack overflow error)
```

Here is the android.manifest configuration for my Activity:

```
<activity
    android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.Base.NoActionBar"
    android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
    android:launchMode="singleTask"
    android:alwaysRetainTaskState="true"
    android:clearTaskOnLaunch="true"
    android:exported="true">
    <intent-filter>
        ... some intent filters ...
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Here is my onConfigurationChanged method where it is looping, as you can see there is nothing fancy happening here. When I debug and examine the newConfig variable, it's exactly the same in each loop:

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.content.ComponentCallbacks2;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements ComponentCallbacks2 {

    ...

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }

    ...

}
```

My MainActivity is basically a viewpager containing fragments with a webview inside of it. Other activities in the same app do not have this issue.

I am using the latest AndroidX libraries:

```
compileSdkVersion 33

defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 23
    targetSdkVersion 33
    ...
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.browser:browser:1.5.0'
    implementation 'androidx.webkit:webkit:1.7.0'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v13:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.9.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-preference-v14:1.0.0'
    ...
}
```

I'm stumped on this one, is there a way I can narrow down what is causing onConfigurationChanged to be constantly calling itself?

Comment: Why does your activity say it implements `ComponentCallbacks2`? What else is your activity class doing?

Comment: @ianhanniballake thank you so much! I implemented ComponentCallbacks2 just to use the onTrimMemory function, but now that I look at it closer it also implements onConfigurationChange, which I had already overridden in my Activity for other reasons, which explains why it was being called recursively. Thanks again for putting me on the right path to find and fix the issue.